# Detect system time and fill an excel file - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get a program to read the server's time, and if it's a time, it pastes the data in an excel sheet, eg if it's 8 am, it pastes the data in the '8am' sheet. I have an excel that has sheets named 8am, 10am, 12am, 14am, 16am and 18am. I need the program to read the server time, if it's 8 am, it pastes the data in the '8am' sheet. I ran it and a range error appeared. Know a better way to do it?

I did it this way:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
        
date_and_hour_current = datetime.now()
timezone = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
date_and_hour_sao_paulo = date_and_hour_current.astimezone(timezone)
date_and_hour_sao_paulo_ib_text = date_and_hour_sao_paulo.strftime('%H')
    
wb_dataframe_request = load_workbook(filename='export_worksheets.xlsx')
    
# Open the workbook by name:
ws_dataframe = wb_dataframe_request['Sheet1']
    
# Open the file where the dataframe information will be copied:
wb_data = load_workbook(filename='file.xlsx')
    
# Time Variables:
ws_data_8 = wb_data['8am']
ws_data_10 = wb_data['10am']
ws_data_12 = wb_data['12am']
ws_data_14 = wb_data['14pm']
ws_data_16 = wb_data['16pm']
ws_data_18 = wb_data['18pm']
    
    if date_and_hour_sao_paulo_in_text == 8:
        ws_data_8 = wb_data['8am']
    
    # Iterates through the worksheet *from* where the information will be copied (ws_dataframe), starting at line 2 (to skip the header) and ending when reaching the line following the last filled line in the file (worksheet_name.max_row + 1):

    for a in range(2, ws_dataframe.max_row + 1):
    
        # Start copying the information in the first column and end the iteration when reaching the first empty column:

        for b in range(1, ws_dataframe.max_column + 1):
            # In the worksheet *to* where the information will be copied, insert in the first empty cell ("a") and in the current column ("b") the value of the current row ("a") and the current column ("b") of the ws_dataframe worksheet:

            ws_data_8.cell(row=a, column=b).value = ws_dataframe.cell(row=a, column=b).value
    
        wb_data.save(r'filepath.xlsx')
    
    else:
        print("ERROR")
```

It appears the "ERROR" that I left fixed in the if, but I don't know where the error is. Do you know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to define the filename that you feed into the `.save()` method as an f string: `filename = f"{fname}.xlsx"`. Then you can run if conditions that assign a value (such as 8am, 10am or whatever) to the variable `fname` based on server time and run the `.save()` method on the filename modified accordingly.